# Combing Rows in a Single Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this, where there is a new row per ID if one of the following columns has a value. I'm trying to combine on the ID, and just consolidate all of the remaining columns. I've tried every groupby/agg combination and can't get the right output. There are no conflicting column values. So for instance if ID "1" has an email value in row 0, the remaining rows will be empty in the column. So I just need it to sum/consolidate, not concatenate or anything.

my current dataframe:
[image]

the output i'm looking to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# fill Nones in string columns with empty string
df[['email', 'status']] = df[['email', 'status']].fillna('')

df = df.groupby('id').agg('max')
```

If you still want the index as you shown in desired output,

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=False)
```